# Download yad with bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, apt, deb

i'm building a simple deb package (single binary) for a little project i've been working on.
Now I want to build a nice interface around it and used zenity for a couple of times, but this time I wanted to use yad.

First I want to download yad so my execuatble script runs the **installyad** file with `gksudo`, so it runs with root privileges. Now you can't just download yad with apt-get install yad, you first need to add the new repository.

installyad file

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yad
echo "Yad installed"
```

Now even when I start a new **gnome-terminal** before this code, it just opens a new terminal but doesn't seem to do anything else.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` will complain if you run it from a script. Try with:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get -q -y update
sudo apt-get -q -y install yad
```

Comment: I want to try your solution but lintian returns an error that this file does not have a manpage. This is because every file in the bin folder needs a manpage i think? But how do i create a lib folder? Where I can copy all my scripts whitout needing a manpage for every single one?